# iOS 16 Beta Issue? - List selection binding parameter is not being updated when items are selected in the list

Tags: swiftui-list, ios16

I have a List with a bound selection field.  The list is populated with a ForEach loop (outline code below)

```
@State private var editMode = EditMode.inactive
@State private var selectedItems = Set<Int>()

List (selection: $selectedItems) {
    ForEach (myObjects.indices, id:\.self) { idx in …….
        Button(…)
    }
}
```

A toolbar action toggles the list edit status by manipulating the editMode parameter.  Visually the list shows rows being selected, however the selectedItems field is never updated.

This works as expected in iOS15.5 - only an issue in iOS16 Betas (up to 3 currently)

I've logged feedback with Apple but thought I'd also post here in case I'm missing something?  Thanks

**Update:**  Still a problem with Beta 4

Comment: Have confirmed with Apple that the issue occurs when using a Button inside the ForEach loop.  They are continuing to investigate.  Suggested alternative is to use .onTapGesture instead of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by Apple in iOS 16.1 beta